# Finding specific sum of a integers in an array

Tags: arrays, loops

Basically this problem asks me to get an input of target_sum and check the integers in the array. If a sum of a pair is equal to target_sum, I need to print it.

I wrote the code like this but it does not work. Where did I make the mistake?

```
void findPair (int arr[],int size,int target_sum)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        for (j=0;j<size;j++){
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == target_sum)
            {
                printf("(%d,%d)",arr[i],arr[j]);
            }       
            else
            {
                printf("No pair.");
            }
            
        }
    }   
}
int main(){
    int arr[] = {8,7,2,5,3,1};
    int target_sum;
    printf("Enter target sum: ");
    scanf("%d",target_sum);
    findPair(arr,6,target_sum);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read what's [on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), How to Ask, and the question checklist, and provide a minimal reproducible example. "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site because SO isn't a free online coding service. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a specific question about your algorithm or technique. (stolen from @Pranav Hosangadi)

Comment: scanf("%d",target_sum); -> scanf("%d",&target_sum);

Comment: A general suggestion since you are a beginner - try debugging (maybe add print statements or use a debugger) your code line by line whenver you get stuck!

Comment: Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As @nsilent22 suggested, `scanf("%d",target_sum);` should be changed into `scanf("%d",&target_sum);`. Besides that, you could have the second for loop start at `j=i+1`, making your code overall look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void findPair (int arr[],int size,int target_sum)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
        for (j=i+1;j<size;j++)
            if (arr[i] + arr[j] == target_sum)
                printf("\n(%d,%d)",arr[i],arr[j]);
            else
                printf("\nNo pair.");
}

int main(){
    int arr[] = {8,7,2,5,3,1};
    int target_sum;
    printf("Enter target sum: ");
    scanf("%d",&target_sum);
    findPair(arr,6,target_sum);
}
```